# how to open multiple activity in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am showing images in view Pager with a button.
 I am trying to open a different Activity for each image when I click on it.

```
    package com.union.pr26;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.View;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ViewPager viewPager;
    CustomeSwipeAdapter adapter;
       ArrayList<Class>list=new ArrayList<Class>();
    list.add(Class(Main2Activity.class))

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        adapter=new CustomeSwipeAdapter(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    public void activity(View v){
     Class activityClass=list.get(1);
        Intent intent =new Intent(this,activityClass);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
    package com.union.pr26;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class CustomeSwipeAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    final int position = 0;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int []imgID ={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2,R.drawable.img3};
    public CustomeSwipeAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx=ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imgID.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(LinearLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view =layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.extra,container,false);
        ImageView imageView =(ImageView)item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(imgID[position]);
        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all it seems you are taking list of activity class which is not at all good. Try to adapt another approach to open activity from adapter. Better way is that try to get position in on Itemclick and open activity accordingly.

Comment: I want to show the images as preview is there any other way then this?

Comment: Yes you just need to open one activity and in that you need to pass path/url of the image using bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Make this, copy and paste this as many times as you want and change it to the activities you want. Make sure you dont open multiple layouts otherwise its going to mess it up. Hope this helps.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainComp_Banner.this, MainComp_Banner_edit.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

Add this to your manifest so that it doesnt crash you, do this for every activity you want to start.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainComp_Banner_edit"
        android:label="EditBanner"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
```